# What library or API can I use to generate possible words/names from a phonetic syllable format?

Tags: library, software-development, c++, api

I am working on a C++ name generator based on machine learning of baby names in the United States. Part of this process is splitting names into their phonetic syllables and generating new names in phonetic syllable format.

**Is there any C/C++ libraries or APIs that can transform a phonetic syllable-formatted word, as in the case of my generated names, into possible spellings?** Any software that you know of that does this already?

Thanks for the help, completely lost on this one; I've never seen a program do this before.